# margin incompatibility between firefox and chrome

Tags: css, wordpress, firefox, cross-browser

I'm customizing a wordpress theme called Canvas, but i'm getting some weird issues.

Firefox is not accepting this CSS property:

## header {margin-top:-130px;}

It works perfectly on Chrome.

Here's the link to my site: http://creatyz.com/yogasalon/

Can anyone help me? I tried everything I could to fix it.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
#header {
    padding: 40px 0px 45px;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    background-size: auto auto;
}
```

to

```
#header {
    padding: 40px 0px 45px;
    position: relative;
    background-size: auto auto;
}
```

or if that is vendor css

add

```
 #header {
     clear: none !important;
 }
```

to your css

(Note the !important is just for testing and should be replaced by something like )

```
#wrapper #header
```

for the selector

Comment: Adding `clear: none !important;` did work! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me as if you are trying to adjust header at just the top of the page?If thats the stuff you can use `top:/*Your value*/;` instead of negetive `margin-top:/*your value*/;`!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.col-full { position: relative; }
header { position: absolute; right: 1em; }
```

and if possible try not work with negative margins...

;]